# How can convert string to date with mongo aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, date, mongoose, aggregation-framework

In a collection, I store this kind of document

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "created_at" : "2016/01/01 12:10:10",
    ...
}.
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "created_at" : "2016/01/04 12:10:10",
    ...
}
```

I would like to find documents have "creared_at" > 2016/01/01 by using  aggregation pipeline.

Anybody have solution to convert "created_at" to date so can conpare in aggregation?

Comment: There is no way to convert string to date in aggregation pipeline, while date to string could be. You may trick: create a copy of your collection and store `created_at` as ISODate and then compare dates...

Comment: You don't actually need to convert anything for your query; `{created_at: {$gt: '2016/01/01'}}` would work fine here because your string format supports meaningful comparison.

Comment: @JohnnyHK: it work so well, i dont recognize it. thank you so much

Answer (score 8):

As you have mentioned, you need to first change your schema so that the `created_at` field holds date objects as opposed to string as is the current situation, then you can query your collection either using the **[`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)** method or the aggregation framework. The former would be the most simple approach.

To convert `created_at` to date field, you would need to iterate the cursor returned by the **[`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)** method using the **[`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** method, within the loop convert the `created_at` field to a Date object and then update the field using the **[`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set)** operator.

Take advantage of using the **[Bulk API](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/bulk-write-operations/)** for bulk updates which offer better performance as you will be sending the operations to the server in batches of say 1000 which gives you a better performance as you are not sending every request to the server, just once in every 1000 requests.

The following demonstrates this approach, the first example uses the Bulk API available in MongoDB versions `>= 2.6 and < 3.2`. It updates all
the documents in the collection by changing the `created_at` fields to date fields:

```
var bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(),
    counter = 0;

db.collection.find({"created_at": {"$exists": true, "$type": 2 }}).forEach(function (doc) {
    var newDate = new Date(doc.created_at);
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({ 
        "$set": { "created_at": newDate}
    });

    counter++;
    if (counter % 1000 == 0) {
        bulk.execute(); // Execute per 1000 operations and re-initialize every 1000 update statements
        bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
})
// Clean up remaining operations in queue
if (counter % 1000 != 0) { bulk.execute(); }
```

The next example applies to the new MongoDB version `3.2` which has since **[deprecated the Bulk API](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/release-notes/3.2/#mongo-shell-and-crud-api)** and provided a newer set of apis using **[`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#db.collection.bulkWrite)**:

```
var cursor = db.collection.find({"created_at": {"$exists": true, "$type": 2 }}),
    bulkOps = [];

cursor.forEach(function (doc) { 
    var newDate = new Date(doc.created_at);
    bulkOps.push(         
        { 
            "updateOne": { 
                "filter": { "_id": doc._id } ,              
                "update": { "$set": { "created_at": newDate } } 
            }         
        }           
    );   

    if (bulkOps.length === 1000) {
        db.collection.bulkWrite(bulkOps);
        bulkOps = [];
    }
});         

if (bulkOps.length > 0) { db.collection.bulkWrite(bulkOps); }
```

Once the schema modification is complete, you can then query your collection for the date:

```
var dt = new Date("2016/01/01");
db.collection.find({ "created_at": { "$gt": dt } });
```

And should you wish to query using the aggregation framework, run the following pipeline to get the desired result. It uses the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** operator, which is similar to the **[`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)** method:

```
var dt = new Date("2016/01/01");
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": { "created_at": { "$gt": dt } }
    }
])
```

Comment: I know this is an oldie, but `db.collection.bulkWrite(bulkUpdateOps);` should be `db.collection.bulkWrite(bulkOps);` in your _Monbodb > v3.2_ answer.

Comment: @PhilippeHaussmann Good spot ;) I have fixed the typo and thank you

Comment: No problem! The code snippet was super helpful for something I'm doing right now.Thank YOU for putting it together! :D

Comment: Could you pls help on this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61165765/mongodb-how-to-parse-date-in-3-6-mongodb-version

Answer (score 8):

All the above answers use `cursors` but however, mongodb always recommend to use `aggregation` pipeline. With the new `$dateFromString` in `mongodb 3.6`, its pretty much simple.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$project:{ created_at:{$dateFromString:{dateString:'$created_at'}}}}
])
```

Comment: Hi Is there any way to search the date as string column as an actual date column without converting it?

Comment: Could anyone pls help on this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61165765/mongodb-how-to-parse-date-in-3-6-mongodb-version

Answer (score 2):

If we have documents:

```
db.doc.save({ "_id" : 1, "created_at" : "2016/01/01 12:10:10" })
db.doc.save({ "_id" : 2, "created_at" : "2016/01/04 12:10:10" })
```

Simple query:

```
db.doc.find({ "created_at" : {"$lte": Date()} })
```

Aggregate query:

```
db.doc.aggregate([{ 
     "$match": { "created_at": { "$lte": Date() } }
}])
```

> - Date() method which returns the current date as a string.
> - new Date() constructor which returns a Date object using the ISODate() wrapper.
> - ISODate() constructor which returns a Date object using the ISODate()
>     wrapper.

More information about the type of date [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/) and [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/Date/)