# How do I convert string to data in Mongo aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In the collection, time stamp field is  stored as a string.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59a780a3da2100974a36cdca"),
    "datetime" : "2016-08-17 0:59"
    ...
}
```

I am tring to convert the string to date in the first stage of Mongo aggregation piple line.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            ts: new Date('$datetime')
        }
    }
])
```

I have done this outside the pipeline, which works fine.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59a780a3da2100974a36cdca"),
    "datetime" : "2016-08-17 0:59",
    "ts" : ISODate("2016-08-17T00:59:00.000-04:00"),
}
```

However, if I do this inside aggregation. I got the following

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59a780a3da2100974a36cdca"),
    "datetime" : "2016-08-17 0:59",
    "ts" : ISODate("1969-12-31T19:00:00.000-05:00")
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string to date in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942931/converting-string-to-date-in-mongodb)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can convert string to date with mongo aggregation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837489/how-can-convert-string-to-date-with-mongo-aggregation)